# check username availability with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am using this function to check username availability when registering, and if the username exist, the submit button is disabled. I'm using a php script to check if the username exists in the database. The code works perfectly in my local server, but when hosted on a Godaddy server, I get the below error when I submit or when I try to navigate to another page:

[image: Empty Response]

After the empty response, I can't access my website for about a minute and then it's fine.

I tried a lot of things like calling jquery.js file before all other js files, but nothing works for me.

I am not very good with jQuery and javascript. Thank you for your suggestions.

ere is the script and the HTML form :

```js
function check_availability_username() {

  var min_chars = 4;
  var max_chars = 30;
  var re = /^\w+$/;
  var characters_error1 = 'Minimum amount of chars is 4';
  var characters_error2 = 'Maximum amount of chars is 30';
  var characters_error3 = 'Chars can be only letters, numbers and underscores!';
  var checking_html = 'Checking...';

  var username = $('#username').val();

  $.post("check_username.php", {
      username: username
    },
    function(result) {

      if (result == 1) {

        if ($('#username').val().length < min_chars) {
          $('#username_availability_result').html(characters_error1);
          $('input[name=submit]').attr('disabled', true);
        } else if ($('#username').val().length > max_chars) {
          $('#username_availability_result').html(characters_error2);
          $('input[name=submit]').attr('disabled', true);
        } else if (!re.test($('#username').val())) {
          $('#username_availability_result').html(characters_error3);
          $('input[name=submit]').attr('disabled', true);
        } else {
          $('#username_availability_result').html(username + ' is Available');
          $('input[name=submit]').attr('disabled', false);
        }
      } else {
        $('#username_availability_result').html(username + ' is not Available');
        $('input[name=submit]').attr('disabled', true);
      }
    });

  if (event.which == 13 || event.keyCode == 13) {

    $.post("check_username.php", {
        username: username
      },
      function(result) {

        if (result == 0) {

          $('#username_availability_result').html(username + ' is not Available');
          $('input[name=submit]').attr('disabled', true);
        }
      });
  }
  
  $('#submit').click(function() {
    $.post("check_username.php", {
        username: username
      },
      function(result) {

        if (result == 0) {

          $('#username_availability_result').html(username + ' is not Available');
          $('input[name=submit]').attr('disabled', true);
        }
      });

  });
}
```

```html
<form id="login-id" action="suscribe-form.php" method="POST" onkeyup="return check_availability_username();">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control button-or-space" name="username" id="username" value="" minlength="4" maxlength="25" required pattern="\w+">
    <input type='hidden' id='check_username_availability' value='Check Availability'>&nbsp;<span id='username_availability_result' name='username_availability_result'></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control button-or-space" name="password1" id="password1" value="" minlength="8" maxlength="60" required pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" onchange="form.password2.pattern = this.value;">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password2">Confirm password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control button-or-space" name="password2" value="" minlength="8" maxlength="60" required pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group pull-right">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-success button-or-space">
  </div>
</form>
```

And here is the php script :

```
<?php    

mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('DB');

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);

$result = mysql_query('select username from user where username = "'.$username.
  '"');

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  echo 0;
} else {
  echo 1;
}

?>
```

Comment: what is the error you are seeing in console?

Comment: Here is the content of the console : Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
http://uwfdb.com/suscribe.php:1 GET http://uwfdb.com/suscribe.php net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution. The problem was not from the jQuery or the php script, i only changed the way i call the function in the form from : onkeyup to onchange, and it is now working like a charm. I hope this tip avoid to others losing hours of time like it did to me. Thank's guys for your suggestions.

Answer (score -2):

If you are getting 500 error that there is problem with the database connection.
check for the included files and connection variables used for database connection.

Hope that will work.

Comment: I don't know what is 500 error, but am not having that i think

Comment: 500 Error has nothing to do with Database Connection